# ATmega88 Brown Out Detection issue

Tags: atmega, brownout

[image: PCB Layout for uC][[image: uC Schematic]]I have a designed based on the ATmega88PA-AUR and am having issues with the Brown Out Detection triggering when it should not be and looking for help.
The uC is powered at +5V, regulated, and external 8MHz crystal.
Problem is when the design is subjected to Radiated Immunity testing (ISO 11452-2) in the 100-200MHz rage, the BOD triggers and resets the micro.
Monitoring the +5V supply to the micro, the voltage level is rock solid and no dips are observed that would indicate triggering the BOD.
I have tried the three different BODLEVEL fuse voltage levels of 1.8, 2.7 and 4.3 and each will still result in a reset during testing.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you monitoring the supply voltage? Do you have a fast scope with the trigger set to catch a very narrow glitch between the Vin and ground pins?  What's your supply decoupling like right at the input voltage pins of the micro?  How about PCB layout?  What's the ground scheme like for the micro?

Comment: Any schematics and PCB layout design would be greatly appreciated to solve the problem. We don't know how to fix something unknown.

Comment: Thank you for your replies,

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I added pics for uC schematic and PCB layout.  2 layer PCB with top and bottom GND planes.  I am using a Saleae scope to monitor +5V supply.  It should be fast enough to capture any glitches, which I am not seeing.

Comment: Well the layout doesn't look terrible, but I would have put the smaller decoupling cap rotated 90 degrees right across the Vin and gnd pins as close as possible to the uC.  No idea if that would fix the problem, but looking for a fast glitch right at the power and ground pins of the device might help find the problem.

Comment: Are there any long traces or wires connected to any of the MCU pins? Maybe there is enough signal being injected into one of them to cause the problem. Are there any areas where there there are signals being radiated from that show up in the emissions part of the test. Maybe adding small caps on other pins is needed to minimize injection.